# PhoneApplicationService.Current.State vs IsolatedStorageSettings windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, tombstoning

I need to pass a large set of data from one page to another. I have two choices as far as I know,
PhoneApplicationService and IsolatedStorageSettings.

PhoneApplicationService creates a lot of delay in when passed between pages. So, I used IsolatedStorageSettings but I am getting some abnormal object creation while removing an item from IsolatedStorageSettings.

which is the best to deal with large complex objects?

What is actually happening while removing items from IsolatedStorageSettings ?

Thanks

EDIT:
When I clear or remove an item from IsolatedStorageSettings, new objects for already stored keys are 
created.

sample code:

```
                if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("FormFields"))
                {
                    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("FormFields", app.response);                       
                }
                else
                {
                    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("FormFields", app.response);                      
                }
```

Comment: So, using `IsolatedStorage` writes data to storage (as is implied). This means that the data is, in essence "permanent" and written to disk, which will cause disk write delays. What you're really looking for is called a `ViewModel` combined with a `ServiceLocator`. What this pattern allows you to do is have one place that stores (basically) singletons of certain classes (`ViewModel`s) which store data needed by the View. You should check out MvvmLight, as they provide a very simple to implement `ViewModel` and `ServiceLocator` which should be portable (as you included both WP7 and WP8).

Comment: Thanks Nate. Yes, what you are saying is right, I have already implemented to maintain the ViewModels so now switching back to a different method involves lot of work, but I am just looking for which is the best way to pass from one page to another.

Comment: The key then is the ServiceLocator. That lets you easily say something like ViewModelLocator.MyPageVM. Then you don't need to pass a reference between pages; they can just retrieve them statically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use the App class?

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public YourDataObject ApplicationDataObject { get; set; }
}
```

You could use it in any page, for example setting values before jumping to the next page:

```
 (Application.Current as App).ApplicationDataObject = new YourDataObject();
```

And retrieving values once you are in the right page:

```
YourDataObject yourData = (Application.Current as  App).ApplicationDataObject;
```

It is not beautiful but it is very simple and perhaps in your case it is the best solution.

Comment: Do you mean it is fast and simple when compared with State and IsolatedStorage? I need the best and optimised way . Thanks

Comment: @PradeepAJ It is as fast and simple as assigning values to global variables. In this case the global variable would be ApplicationDataObject, once you do not need the values you can set null value and GC should release the memory.

Comment: yes, this is the best way for my current implementation. Thanks